# Multiple-machine deployment scenario

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, installation

I have a virtual machine (let's call it machine no.1) on which I have installed Microsoft SQL Express 2008 R+ ArcSDE 10.0+ ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 +ArcGIS Server 10.0. Everything is connected and works just fine.

Now I've installed ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 on another machine (machine no.2) and I want to connect to the Database Server on machine no.1.

Should I install ArcSDE 10.1 on machine no.1?

If I try to Add a NEW Database Server on machine no.2, I get the error " Failed to connect to Database Server".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found out that I couldn't connect to the Database Server because of a firewall block.